# Cocoa Touch - Handling touches that get interrupted or lost

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a couple places in my app where UI elements reset themselves when a touch ends on them. For example, hiding a dashed outline, sliding a view back to the default position.

The problem is that on occasion the app loses track of the touches. One example is if I slide the view upward and cause a UIAlertView to show, the view doesn't slide back, because the reset code is in touches ended. The touch ends during the time the UIAlertView is active, and the view doesn't reset. The same example works for hiding the dashed outlines.

My question is, where/how can I handle the reseting of these custom UI elements so that when a touch ends without being noticed it will still reset. TouchesEnded isn't always doing it for me.

Comment: Just tried using touches canceled, but that didn't work out.

Comment: If that doesn't work you should file a bug. I think it's probably supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try touchesCancelled? I think it is called when the touch get interrupted.

EDIT: If this doesn't work then maybe you can manually add code that cancel the touch when you initiate the alert.